# How to send ouput of branch if to pipe

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, getopts

having this script:

```
if getopts "i" i; then
  grep -i | a lot of commands
else
  grep | a lot of commands
fi
```

The question is, I do not want to duplicate `a lot of commands` after the first entry to pipe, but the entry derive from a branch (whether `getopts` return 0 or 1). I want something like `grep ${i:-defauloption} | ...` and the `defaultoption` depends on the branch result - that is embed the branch before piped, rather then duplicating the `a lot of commands` with `else` branch, but just without the option (duplicated code). Is it possible to somehow avoid the duplication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with

```
if getopts "i" i; then
  grep -i 
else
  grep
fi | a lot of commands
```

Comment: I didnt know, I can pass `fi` to pipe

Comment: I have another problem, When I do what you said, and execute with `-i` then it will execute `grep -i -i` with two `i` options set. Why?

Comment: You are not passing `fi` to pipe, you are passing the output of the `if..then..else..fi` conditional construct.

Comment: About the double `-i`, I have no idea. You didn't showed the full code.

Comment: here is full code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61566331/why-is-optind-messing-my-positional-params

Comment: Because you are re-using the arguments that have already been parsed by getopts. Take a look at the answer by Walter A, as it also solves this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Store the variable part in a variable.

```
if getopts "i" i; then
  myoptions="-i"
fi
grep ${myoptions} | a lot of commands
```

Comment: I do not see positional params because of the `getopts`. The options messes with the input params. I somewhere found to do `((OPTIND -1))` - but I do not understand what that mean. but that doesnt work in my case, since I used the params in the branches, not after (the `((OPTIND-1))` should be used after `esac` according to some other questions. So how can I used options flag, and AFTER input params on invocation?

Comment: I hoped you knew what you was doing with the isolated `getopts` and `grep` command. The `getopts` call will look at an environment variable OPTIND and add one to it. To start over with the first argument, start a new shell or use `OPTIND=1`. When you want to parse the input variables, copy some `getopts` example with a `while` loop, and only parse the input in the loop. After the loop use the option variables that you have set. Or ask a new question when you are stuck with `getopts` in different situations.

Comment: @Watler A : here is full code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61566331/why-is-optind-messing-my-positional-params