# Why is OPTIND messing my positional params?

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, getopts

I have this function:

```
    sgrep () 
{ 
    local OPTIND;
    if getopts i o; then
        grep --color=auto -P -in "$1" "$2";
        shift $((OPTIND-1));
    else
        grep --color=auto -P -n "$1" "$2";
    fi | sed -E -n 's/^([0-9]+).*/\1/p' | xargs -I{} vim +"{}" "$2";
    stty sane
}
```

It should use grep case sensitive, if it is invoke with `-i`. But when it is, the it put `-i` is in place of `search string` and `search string` is in place of `somefile`:

```
$ set -x
$ sgrep 'somesearch' 'somefile'
---#output---
+ sgrep -i 'somesearch' 'somefile'
+ local OPTIND
+ sed -E -n 's/^([0-9]+).*/\1/p'
+ getopts i o
+ grep --color=auto -P -in -i 'somesearch'
```

In invocation, the grep takes the `$1` (which should be search string), as `-i`, so the search string is in place of `file` and therefor not invokes (respect. waiting for file or stdin - as grep does without file specified). I thought the `$((OPTIND-1))` would shift the one option out according to this [Explain the shell command: shift $(($optind - 1))](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/214141/explain-the-shell-command-shift-optind-1/214151) but it does not. 1) Can someone explain? + little explanation of the `$OPTIND` in my case would be good as well. 2) last question: why does `|| exit 1 |` does not exit before another pipe when grep fail?

Comment: The variables `OPTIND` and `opt` are both global, meaning that each time you run the function, it inherits leftover values from previous runs. Make them local ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16654607/using-getopts-inside-a-bash-function/16655341#16655341)). Also, the usual form for `getopts` is a `while` loop (rather than `if`), with the `shift `$((OPTIND-1))` *after* it.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I did use `if` because I have just one option. 2) I do not understand why global `opt` mess the index of params. It store a value not index, so it would not have any affect on my problem. So rather make local ONLY `$OPTIND`?

Comment: Look at my update. Added `local` but did not helped

Comment: Can’t you replace the whole if-else-fi tree with just `grep —color=auto -P -n $@` or something similar? That should copy all the arguments you gave to the function, including the `-i` if it is there

Comment: @JimDanner I could, but that would make `getopts` out of play. I want to understand, how it works, and parse its arguments. So no for this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Question 1, `getopts` problems:

As I said in a comment, you need to make `OPTIND` and `opt` local to the function, so it doesn't inherit values from previous runs of the function. To understand why this is, let me start with your original function (from the first version of your question), and add some instrumentation in the form of `echo` commands to show how things change as it runs:

```
sgrep () 
{ 
    echo "Starting sgrep, OPTIND='$OPTIND', opt='$opt', args=$*" >&2
    if getopts "i" i; then
        opt="-i";
        shift $((OPTIND-1));
        echo "Parsed -$i flag, OPTIND='$OPTIND', opt='$opt', args=$*" >&2
    fi;
    echo "Done parsing,   OPTIND='$OPTIND', opt='$opt', args=$*" >&2
    # grep --color=auto -P ${opt} "$1" "$2" || exit 1 | sed -E -n 's/^([0-9]+)/\1/p' | xargs -I{} vim +"{}" "$2";
}
```

...and try running that, first with no `-i` flag:

```
$ sgrep 'somesearch' 'somefile'
Starting sgrep, OPTIND='1', opt='', args=somesearch somefile
Done parsing,   OPTIND='1', opt='', args=somesearch somefile
```

And it worked fine! After parsing, `opt` is empty (as it should be), and both "somesearch" and "somefile" remain in the argument list to be passed to `grep`.

I should explain a little about `OPTIND`, though, before going on. `getopts` is designed to be run repeatedly to iterate through the flag (aka option) arguments, and `OPTIND` is part of how it keeps track of where it is in processing the argument list. In particular, it's the number of the *next* argument that it needs to examine to see if it's a flag (and process it if it is). In this case, it start off at 1 (i.e. `$1` is the next arg to examine), and it stays there because `$1` is a regular argument, not a flag.

BTW, if you'd done `shift $((OPTIND-1))` after processing as usual, it'd do `shift 0`, which would all zero flag arguments from the arg list. Just as it should. (On the other hand, if you had a loop and put `shift` inside the loop, it'd change the arg list out from under `getopts`, causing it to lose track of its place and get very confused. That's why you put the `shift` *after* the loop.)

Ok, let's try it with an actual flag:

```
$ sgrep -i 'somesearch' 'somefile'
Starting sgrep, OPTIND='1', opt='', args=-i somesearch somefile
Parsed -i flag, OPTIND='2', opt='-i', args=somesearch somefile
Done parsing,   OPTIND='2', opt='-i', args=somesearch somefile
```

Again, it worked properly! It parsed the `-i`, set `opt` appropriately, incremented `OPTIND` to 2 so if you'd had a loop it would've examined the second argument, found it's a regular argument, and stopped the loop. And then `shift $((OPTIND-1))` shifted off the one flag argument, leaving the non-flag ones to be passed to `grep`.

Let's try it again, with the same flag:

```
$ sgrep -i 'somesearch' 'somefile'
Starting sgrep, OPTIND='2', opt='-i', args=-i somesearch somefile
Done parsing,   OPTIND='2', opt='-i', args=-i somesearch somefile
```

Oops, now it's all gone screwy, and it's because it inherited `OPTIND` and `opt` from the previous run. `OPTIND` being 2 tells `getopts` that it's already examined `$1` and doesn't have to process it again; it looks at `$2`, sees it doesn't start with `-` so it isn't a flag, so it returns false, and the `if` doesn't run and the flag argument doesn't get shifted away. Meanwhile, `opt` is still set to "`-i`" from the last run.

*That* is why `getopts` hasn't been working right for you. To prove it, let's modify the function to make both variables local:

```
sgrep ()
{
    local OPTIND opt    # <- This is the only change here
    echo "Starting sgrep, OPTIND='$OPTIND', opt='$opt', args=$*" >&2
    if getopts "i" i; then
        opt="-i";
        shift $((OPTIND-1));
        echo "Parsed -$i flag, OPTIND='$OPTIND', opt='$opt', args=$*" >&2
    fi;
    echo "Done parsing,   OPTIND='$OPTIND', opt='$opt', args=$*" >&2
    # grep --color=auto -P ${opt} "$1" "$2" || exit 1 | sed -E -n 's/^([0-9]+)/\1/p' | xargs -I{} vim +"{}" "$2";
}
```

And try it out:

```
$ sgrep -i 'somesearch' 'somefile'
Starting sgrep, OPTIND='', opt='', args=-i somesearch somefile
Parsed -i flag, OPTIND='2', opt='-i', args=somesearch somefile
Done parsing,   OPTIND='2', opt='-i', args=somesearch somefile
$ sgrep -i 'somesearch' 'somefile'
Starting sgrep, OPTIND='', opt='', args=-i somesearch somefile
Parsed -i flag, OPTIND='2', opt='-i', args=somesearch somefile
Done parsing,   OPTIND='2', opt='-i', args=somesearch somefile
```

Now it starts off a little weird because `OPTIND` is blank instead of 1, but that's not actually a problem because `getopts` assumes it should start at 1. So it parses the argument, sets `opt` (which *didn't* inherit a bogus value from before), and shifts the flag out of the argument list.

There is a problem, though. Suppose we pass an illegal (/unsupported) flag:

```
$ sgrep -k 'somesearch' 'somefile'
Starting sgrep, OPTIND='', opt='', args=-k somesearch somefile
-bash: illegal option -- k
Parsed -? flag, OPTIND='2', opt='-i', args=somesearch somefile
Done parsing,   OPTIND='2', opt='-i', args=somesearch somefile
```

Oops again. Since `getopts` processed an argument starting with `-`, it printed an error but went ahead and returned true with the variable `i` set to "?" to indicate there was a problem. Your system didn't check that, it just assumed it must be `-i`.

Now, let me show you the standard (recommended) version, with a `while` loop and a `case` on the flag, with an error handler. I've also taken the liberty of removing single semicolons from the end of lines, 'cause they're useless in shell:

```
sgrep ()
{
    local OPTIND opt
    echo "Starting sgrep, OPTIND='$OPTIND', opt='$opt', args=$*" >&2
    while getopts "i" i; do
        case "$i" in
            i )
                opt="-$i"
                echo "Parsed -$i flag, OPTIND='$OPTIND', opt='$opt', args=$*" >&2
                ;;
            * )
                return 1 ;;
        esac
    done
    shift $((OPTIND-1))
    echo "Done parsing,   OPTIND='$OPTIND', opt='$opt', args=$*" >&2
    # grep --color=auto -P ${opt} "$1" "$2" || exit 1 | sed -E -n 's/^([0-9]+)/\1/p' | xargs -I{} vim +"{}" "$2"
}
```

And run it:

```
$ sgrep 'somesearch' 'somefile'
Starting sgrep, OPTIND='', opt='', args=somesearch somefile
Done parsing,   OPTIND='1', opt='', args=somesearch somefile
$ sgrep -i 'somesearch' 'somefile'
Starting sgrep, OPTIND='', opt='', args=-i somesearch somefile
Parsed -i flag, OPTIND='2', opt='-i', args=-i somesearch somefile
Done parsing,   OPTIND='2', opt='-i', args=somesearch somefile
$ sgrep 'somesearch' 'somefile'
Starting sgrep, OPTIND='', opt='', args=somesearch somefile
Done parsing,   OPTIND='1', opt='', args=somesearch somefile
$ sgrep -i 'somesearch' 'somefile'
Starting sgrep, OPTIND='', opt='', args=-i somesearch somefile
Parsed -i flag, OPTIND='2', opt='-i', args=-i somesearch somefile
Done parsing,   OPTIND='2', opt='-i', args=somesearch somefile
```

...Parsing works as expected, even with repeated runs. Check the error handling:

```
$ sgrep -k 'somesearch' 'somefile'
Starting sgrep, OPTIND='', opt='', args=-k somesearch somefile
-bash: illegal option -- k
```

And since there's a loop, it handles multiple flags (even if there's only one defined flag):

```
$ sgrep -i -i -i -i 'somesearch' 'somefile'
Starting sgrep, OPTIND='', opt='', args=-i -i -i -i somesearch somefile
Parsed -i flag, OPTIND='2', opt='-i', args=-i -i -i -i somesearch somefile
Parsed -i flag, OPTIND='3', opt='-i', args=-i -i -i -i somesearch somefile
Parsed -i flag, OPTIND='4', opt='-i', args=-i -i -i -i somesearch somefile
Parsed -i flag, OPTIND='5', opt='-i', args=-i -i -i -i somesearch somefile
Done parsing,   OPTIND='5', opt='-i', args=somesearch somefile
```

Now, you might complain that that's a lot of code for such a simple task (just one possible flag!), and you'd be right. But it's basically boilerplate; you don't have to write that whole thing every time, just copy a standard example, fill in the options string and cases to handle them, and that's pretty much it. If it weren't in a function you wouldn't have the `local` command, and you'd use `exit 1` instead of `return 1` to bail out, but that's about it.

If you really want it to be simple, just use `if [ "$1" = "-i" ]`, and don't get involved with the complexities of using `getopts`.

## Question 2, why does `|| exit 1 |` does not exit before another pipe when grep fail?:

There are actually three problems with that approach: first, to exit a function you use `return` instead of `exit`.

Second, the shell parses pipes with higher precedence than `||` so the command was treated as:

```
    grep --color=auto -P ${opt} "$1" "$2"
Logical or'ed with:
    exit 1 | sed -E -n 's/^([0-9]+)/\1/p' | xargs -I{} vim +"{}" "$2"
```

Rather than

```
    grep --color=auto -P ${opt} "$1" "$2" || exit 1
Piped to:
    sed -E -n 's/^([0-9]+)/\1/p' | xargs -I{} vim +"{}" "$2"
```

Third, and most importantly, the elements of a pipeline run in subprocesses. For shell commands like `exit` and `return`, that means they run in subshells, and running `exit` or `return` (or `break` or ...) in a subshell doesn't have that effect on the parent shell (i.e the one running the function). That means there's nothing you can do within the pipeline to make the function return directly.

In this case, I think your best option is something like:

```
grep ... | otherstuff
if [ "${PIPESTATUS[0]}" -ne 0 ]; then
    return 1
fi
```

Comment: I how just one question. In the command, I am opening vim according to a number of line. The problem is, it is slow. Is it possible in my function to open it asynchronously? or in the background? How to do asynchronous pipes?

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the positional params to one bigger:

```
sgrep () 
    { 
        local OPTIND;
        if getopts i o; then
            grep --color=auto -P -in "$2" "$3";
            shift $((OPTIND-1));
        else
            grep --color=auto -P -n "$1" "$2";
        fi | sed -E -n 's/^([0-9]+).*/\1/p' | xargs -I{} vim +"{}" "$2";
        stty sane
    }
```

Which works, but I don't like it. In one branch I have to use bigger positions, because of the option, but on the other branch without option used, positions do not change. It is messy

I have tried to put `shift $((OPTIND-1))` immediately after `then` but for no avail.